# Responsive html, with fixed aspect ratio and screen fill

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive webpage, with fixed ratio of 16x10.
The code below works so far. The only problem I have at the moment is that when the width grows too big, and page needs to be scrolled.

The wanted behaviour is that the page will fill the browser window, without being cropped in any direction, while keeping wanted ratio.

Thanks!

My HTML snippet:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="innerContent">
        <div id="header">...</div>
        <div id="menuBar">...</div>
        <div id="content">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS snippet:

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5vw;
    text-align: center;
}
#innerContent{
    padding: 2vw;
}
#header {
    position: relative;   
    height: 7vw;
}
#menuBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vw;
}

#content {
    height: 36vw;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: By definition, having a fixed aspect ratio for your webpage is not [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: Alas, that is the client demand. Fixed aspect ratio of the design, while keeping responsiveness and just scaling when moving between resolutions...

Comment: Have you tried giving your elements `#content` and `#menuBar` a `max-width`? Or you can use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) so you give your elements a steady size (width and/or height) when the screen size is a certain width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found my own solution.
Used media queries to define fixed resolutions for the wrapper, and used javascript to define fixed height calculated using from percentages in order to be able to use percentage width for the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad design, so I'd try to convince the client to do it differently.

If that fails, you could possibly use a similar technique to having fixed ratio images and videos. You set the height to 0 and add padding equivalent to ratio in %. Padding is calculated as a % of the width.

```
#wrapper {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: percentage(10/16);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#innerContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/obPgYe

note: the calculation for this uses a sass function

Comment: Thanks, but the bottom is still cropped... Looking for a way to keep it from being cropped...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The innerContent div is 1333 x 833 pixes on my laptop - a 16/10 ratio.

Comment: @JamieC From my understanding, he wants the content to be the same aspect ratio but limit the height and width so it will fit in the current browser window size.

Comment: ah yes, from the original question "The wanted behaviour is that the page will fill the browser window, without being cropped in any direction, while keeping wanted ratio.". This isn't possible as the the browser window is set by the user. e.g. what ff you're viewing full screen on a monitor that isn't a 16/10 ratio? You could re-size the browser window using javacript, but this is a horribly obtrusive practice that thankfully fell out of fashion over a decade ago. It also won't work on mobile devices that only have a full screen bowser view.

Comment: No need for mobile support. The wanted behaviour is to change the margin size in order to not let the page crop...

Comment: What on earth is the use case for this? I don't see how this would work beyond only a small amount of scaling. Your container is going to shrink, but your content will not, which will break your design at some point.

Comment: All I need is just scaling... I'm taking care of the content size, I don't know how to take care of the outer margin...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with only CSS, you'll have to use some javascript.

First we'll need to get the width and height of our window and work out the ratio:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var ratio = height / width;
```

We'll need to handle the caculation differently depending on if the window ratio is larger or smaller than 10/16:

```
var wrapperHeight, wrapperWidth;
if (ratio >= 10/16) {
  wrapperWidth = width;
  wrapperHeight = width / 1.6; 
} else {
  wrapperHeight = height;
  wrapperWidth = height * 1.6;
}
wrapper.style.height = wrapperHeight + 'px';
wrapper.style.width = wrapperWidth + 'px';
```

Then we need to do this calculation when the page loads and when the window resizes.

```
window.onload = setRatio;
window.onresize = setRatio;
```

http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/obPgYe

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but still doesn't meet the requirements... I don't want to change the window size, just the margin values...
the wrapper should be centered in the window, and shouldn't grow to be cropped.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the wrapper container is never set to be wider or taller than the content area of the window. If you want to center align it,  just add `margin: 0 auto` to the wrapper.

Comment: ofcourse, you are correct.
I mean that the body background will be around the centered content area and fill the screen. the browser should be full screen, in each and every resolution.

Comment: But you can't control if the user has their browser at fullscreen, or what aspect ratio they have. Personally I think you're trying to solve a problem that isn't worth solving. You're going to put a lot of effort into producing something that will be a poor user experience for most. If you really want to, you're going to need to use some javascript to detect the dimensions of the viewable content area and adjust things based on that, you should be able to do this by adapting the above.

Comment: If mean you don't want this to be fluid (i.e. changes when the user resizes the window), remove `window.onresize = setRatio;`.